# Как в Vs code изменить терминал по умолчанию?

Tags: консоль, visual-studio-code

Как в Vs code изменить терминал по умолчанию? Не хочу использовать терминал по умолчанию, так как там не работают некоторые команды. И хочу изменить чтобы при нажатии открыть терминал, появлялся любой другой, но не встроенный powershell. Например можно терминал Bash или PowerShell. Если что, то первый и второй powershell они отличаются, первый встроенный в Vs code, а другой с расширения. И второй у меня работает.